# Scenekit snapshot() doesn't include camera exposure settings

Tags: swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I'm providing screenshot functionality for my AR app, and I noticed that the screenshots I take (via `sceneView.snapshot()`) are much darker than what I see from the camera. I'm using the ARKit example code from Apple, and it seems like this is affecting it:

```
camera.wantsHDR = true
camera.wantsExposureAdaptation = true
camera.exposureOffset = -1
camera.minimumExposure = -1
camera.maximumExposure = 3
```

When I remove the exposure settings, the snapshot works fine. Any way to make sure the snapshot considers those exposure settings?

Comment: im not 100% sure about this (as i have done very little with ARKit) but i think there is a variable `sceneView.automaticallyUpdatesLighting = true` try that and see if it helps

Comment: Have you already read this article? It also explains the lighting of the sceneView https://blog.markdaws.net/arkit-by-example-part-4-realism-lighting-pbr-b9a0bedb013e

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED: November 25, 2019**.

#First Reason

The main reason that snapshots taken in AR apps are darker than a video stream coming from a rear RGB camera is because you have two absolutely different scenes: the first one is SCNScene with 3D models having its own exposure and the second one is a RGB camera's view with its own exposure. In ARSCNView these exposures are added together forming an **average exposure** value, what can be **darker** (like in your case) or can be **lighter**.

#Second Reason

Also, you need to take into account a `whitePoint` instance property also known as a luminance level for use as the upper end of a [tone mapping curve](http://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs129/results/proj5/valayshah/).

```
var whitePoint: CGFloat { get set }
```

> When using a High Dynamic Range (HDR) camera, SceneKit applies a process called tone mapping to translate the wide range of luminance values in the visible scene to the narrower range of brightness values that can be shown on a display. SceneKit determines a tone mapping curve from the `minimumExposure`, `maximumExposure`, `exposureOffset`, and `whitePoint` properties, along with a measure of scene luminance.

The default value of `whitePoint` is `1.0`. By setting this property to a higher or lower value, you can produce more gradual or more abrupt transitions between shadows and highlights. This property has no effect if the `wantsHDR` value is `false`.

```
camera.whitePoint = 1.5
```

#Third Reason

Color models of RGB camera stream, rendered SCNView and an iPhone's display are slightly different in Gamma Correction.